# Django NoReverseMatch at logout function error

Tags: python, html, django, view

I am encountering such an error in the logout part of my Django project. I tried many ways with examples I searched on the internet, but the error does not go away.

layout.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}

    






    
    
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
```

dash.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html'%}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-logo">
      Ox.v1
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar-navigation">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Anasayfa
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Dashboard
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i> Infotmation
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i> Users
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'logout_view' %}">
            <i class="fas fa-outdent"></i> Exit
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
 
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import connections
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import logout



def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('dash')
        else:
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'pages/login.html')

def dash(request):

    return render(request, 'pages/dash.html')



def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.login,name='login'),
    path('zZ6jMGa8tBHYcjPS/',views.dash,name='dash'),
    
]
```

error

```
Reverse for 'logot_view' not found. 'logot_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *function* registered as logout_view() however you have no URL pattern to route it anywhere.

Your urls.py should be like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.login,name='login'),
path('zZ6jMGa8tBHYcjPS/',views.dash,name='dash'),
path('logout/',views.logout_view,name='logout_view'),

]
```